# Visual Studio 2019 Unable to Convert Runtime Connection String to Its Design-Time Equivalent

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, edmx

I am using `Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.5.5` and `SQL Server 2016` on Windows 10.

When I want to `Update Model from Database` then I get the following error message:

[image]

My EDMX connection string is as follows:

```
metadata=res://*/Model.FruitShopEntities.csdl|res://*/Model.FruitShopEntities.ssdl|res://*/Model.FruitShopEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=.\SQL2016;initial catalog=FruitShop;integrated security=False;User Id: sa; Password: 1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
```

I have googled but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Try using the `=` character to seperate keys and values, not the `:` character.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, you are correct. Thank you.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, AlwaysLearning meant change "User Id: sa" to "User Id= sa". Don't do this for "res:"